# boost::asio::async_write issue over serial channel

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have client server application, the flow is as explained below:

client is at windows side and do not use boost
server is at linux side and uses boost
client-server communicates over serial channel RS485. and server uses `boost::asio::async_write`.

```
client --> calls command with specific command_id --> server
client <-- sends acknowledgement                  <-- server
{server process the command, meanwhile the client is blocked for response}
client <-- sends response                         <-- server
```

Sometimes what happens client receives the acknowledgement but do not receive the response even if the response is sent by the server.
The pending response is later received by the client when client sends another command.

If I use `boost::asio::write` for serial communication there is no problem at all.

below is the code snippet for async_write

```
boost::asio::async_write(serial_port, boost::asio::buffer(&v_chunk[0], v_chunk.size()),
        boost::bind(&Serial_channel::async_write_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

io_serv->run();
io_serv->reset();
```

Comment: On the "server" side, you are running the `io_service` event loop properly?

Comment: yes @Joachim I have used io_service loop correctly. just after async_write I have used io_service.run() and reset().

Comment: @Chirag Desai why `reset`? Can you show the code? Most likely, `io_service` gets out of work.

Comment: Since the functions are asynchronous, you need to run the io service continuously. You can't really say when your `async_write` call will be dispatched, so if you stop the event loop prematurely then the write will not happen.

Comment: @igor I use reset as I want to use io_service.run multiple time.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg cant get your point

Comment: thnx @JoachimPileborg as per your statement "stop the event loop prematurely" I have put sleep and it worked. Now the flow I used is async_write() then to block used run() and before reset() put a sleep of 1 milli second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referencing @Joachim comment I have changed my flow like below and it worked.

```
boost::asio::async_write(serial_port, boost::asio::buffer(&v_chunk[0], v_chunk.size()),
        boost::bind(&Serial_channel::async_write_callback, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

io_serv->run();
usleep(1000); // 1 millisecond delay
io_serv->reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you use the `io_service` will not work. First of all the `run` function doesn't return until the service event loop is stopped. Secondly, if you just want to use it as a "poller" then you should use [`poll`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll.html) or optionally [`poll_one`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll_one.html) (or perhaps [`run_one`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run_one.html)).

But if you do it like that, it's the same as doing a non-async `write` call, and you loos the benefits of the async functions.

Comment: I use async_write just in case I require to stop the operation. Otherwise synchronous write operation would be suffice. I want the async_write to behave like synchronous write and hence used run(). The functionality works great. But somehow the client do not receive the data server has already sent.

Comment: Now do you get my question?

Comment: @ChiragDesai And the problem is still that you might stop the event loop early, before the `async_write` function finishes. Something you say you might want to do, and it's actually what happens when the messages you want to be sent are not.

Comment: ok then if I move reset before async_write then do you think it work? In that case my flow will be first reset as I might sent data using async_write previously then async_write and then run(). Does it make sense?